# Need help with pivot for this table sql server

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a table with the following structure

```
uid  sid  eid   Key     value
1    1     1   F.Name   Simon 
2    1     1   L.Name   Jones
3    1     1   C.Name   AAPL
4    1     1   Address  Infinite
5    2     1   F.Name   Brad
6    2     1   L.Name   Pitt
7    2     1   C.Name   Holly
8    2     1   Address  LA
```

I would like to convert the above table to below format

```
sid  F.Name  L.Name  C.Name  Address
1    Simon   Jones   AAPL    Infinite
2    Brad    Pitt    Holly   LA
```

Basically I need values of "Key" column to be column fields in new table. I have no other table. Even Linq to sql is ok and I can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `2005` and later:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  sid, key, value
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
PIVOT   (
        MIN(value)
        FOR
        key IN ([F.Name], [L.Name], [C.Name], [Address])
        ) p
```

Comment: @user281693, was just going to write an Entity Framework solution but if this works this will be much easier for you. Let us know if it works or not.

Comment: @Quassnoi : Thanks and it works. What if I do not know what the values are in "Key" column of the original table. That is I do not know that in "Key" column there are F.Name, L.Name, C.Name, Address. These are coming from another application and I might have simplified it to post it on SO. I do not know if I make sense.

Comment: @user: then you will have to build a list of all possible keys using one query and use it to build another query (similar to the query I posted) using dynamic `SQL`. With static `SQL` it is not possible to build queries with variable column layout.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thanks did some search in Google about dynamic sql and found this http://sqldeveloperramblings.blogspot.com/2010/02/quick-tip-003-dynamic-pivot-sql.html.